# How to change upload text language?

Tags: html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3.1 . 
How to change upload text language ?

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

I want to change `Choose File - No file chosen` default English language to other.
I tried this but not worked.

```
<input type="file" name="file" value="new language" />
```

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure that comes automatically with the browser language so you actually wouldn't need to set it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type='file'/>
    <span id='val'></span>
    <span id='button'>Select File</span>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
})

$("input[type='file']").change(function(){
   $('#val').text(this.value.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''))
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a8qN2/586/)**

Comment: I don't know it still showing me `Choose File - No file chosen`

Comment: have you add css and javascript ? or may be css config.

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238671/ajax-upload-not-working-codeigniter ?