# Ajax upload not working codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1 . I want to post upload data using ajax.

Ajax upload file not working. But when i post the simple form without ajax, it working fine.

I don't know why but no error in console.

**HTML**

```
  <?php echo form_open_multipart(site_url("upload/post"), ['id' => 'uploader']) ?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   $('#uploader').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href + '/post',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData(this)
               });
      });
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
 public function post() 
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library("upload");
        $file = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("userfile"));

        $this->upload->initialize(array( 
               "upload_path" => 'upload',
               "overwrite" => FALSE,
               "max_filename" => 300,
               "encrypt_name" => TRUE
            ));

        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $image_file = $data['file_name'];

  }
```

Comment: You are not passing file to upload class i.e. `$file`. After initialization you should have something like `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){/*code*/}`. Check the basic example of upload [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller).

Comment: I already tried but not working.

Comment: What is the error? `var_dump('$this->input->post('userfile');exit;` to check if PHP is getting those data.

Comment: No error found. I have more inputs and all are working fine but the file upload not working.

Comment: You need to choose wether to use AJAX or default form posting. This way PHP is redirecting page before JS finishes it's job. If you want to use AJAX, you would need to combine some JS library for upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues is that file uploading uses a different mechanism than the other form `<input>` types. That is why `$this->input->post("userfile")` isn't getting the job done for you. Other answers have suggested using javascript's `FormData` and this one does too.

**HTML**

A very simple form for picking a file and submitting it. Note the change from a simple button to `<input type="submit"...`. Doing so makes it a lot easier for the javascript to use the `FormData` object.

[FormData documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
        <title>Upload Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?= form_open_multipart("upload/post", ['id' => 'uploader']); ?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </p>
        <?php echo form_close() ?>

        <div id="message"></div>

        <script>
            $('#uploader').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: window.location.href + '/post',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.result === true) {
                            $("#message").html("<p>File Upload Succeeded</p>");
                        } else {
                            $("#message").html("<p>File Upload Failed!</p>");
                        }
                        $("#message").append(data.message);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

Use `FormData` to capture the fields.
Note that instead of handling the button click we handle the submit event.

```
$('#uploader').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href + '/post',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //uncomment the next line to log the returned data in the javascript console
            // console.log(data);
            if (data.result === true) {
                $("#message").html("<p>File Upload Succeeded</p>");
            } else {
                $("#message").html("<p>File Upload Failed!</p>");
            }
            $("#message").append(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

I've added some code that "reports" results to ajax and will display it on the upload page.

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(['form', 'url']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_v');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        $this->load->library("upload");
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
                "upload_path" => './uploads/',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt',
                "overwrite" => FALSE,
                "max_filename" => 300,
                "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
        ));

        $successful = $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

        if($successful)
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $image_file = $data['file_name'];
            $msg = "<p>File: {$image_file}</p>";
            $this->data_models->update($this->data->INFO, array("image" => $image_file));
        } else {
            $msg = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

        echo json_encode(['result' => $successful, 'message' => $msg]);
    }

}
```

This will upload your file. Your work probably isn't done because I suspect that your are not saving all the file info you need to the db. That, and I suspect you are going to be surprised by the name of the uploaded file.

I suggest you study up on how PHP [handles file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and examine some of the similar codeigniter related questions on file uploads here on SO.

Comment: Forgot to mention this in the answer but I had to change the upload directory name from `upload` to `uploads`. Maybe you missed that? Other than `data_models->update()` which is a model I don't have the answer code worked for me. When you say, "not working." what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Thanks now working. The problem is in my php but i fixed it :)

Comment: All working fine but success function not working. `success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data); }` not showing.

Comment: But the file uploads OK?

Comment: Yes all working fine but success function not working.

Comment: Please forgive if is insulting. You know how to view the java console - right.

Comment: Do you see the any network traffic coming back from the ajax request? You can examine the response and see what, if anything, the server sends back.

Comment: I am using AJAX Debugger Preferences chrome extension and i get this error from console `VM5547:3 XHR Loaded (post - 200 OK - 260.44399999955203ms - 601B)
VM5549:3 http://localhost/post
VM5550:3 XHR Data Object {startedDateTime: "2016-11-01T20:30:47.384Z", time: 260.44399999955203, request: Object, response: Object, cache: Object…}`

Comment: `VM5547:3` sources = `(function (json_args) {
 var args = JSON.parse(unescape(json_args));
 console[args[0]].apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
})('%5B%22group%22%2C%22XHR%20Loaded%20%28updatepropic%20-%20200%20OK%20-%20260.44399999955203ms%20-%20601B%29%22%5D');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127134/discussion-between-dfriend-and-mehur).

Comment: Finally i fixed it by removing `dataType: 'json',` , and now working fine. Please update answer. Thank you for all help :)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to this would be passing to PHP the file encoded in base64:

- get the selected file from `#userfile` field using `$('#userfile').prop('files')[0]`;
- transform the contents of that file into a base64 encoded string using [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). We're going to call this `content`; Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978156/get-base64-encode-file-data-from-input-form) showing how to do and expanding the answer & possibilities;
- send the AJAX passing both the `filename` and `content` strings;
- now on CI, fetch the POST data;
- base64_decode() the `content`;
- fwrite() the result into a file using the `filename`.

That way also you could avoid POSTing all form fields.

Comment: what happened, exactly?

Comment: Getting error `upload:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)`

Comment: I think thats on me, sry, just edited the answer. Could you please try to replace the `$('#userfile').attr('files')[0];` with `$('#userfile').prop('files')[0];`?

Comment: Still not working . Getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)`

Comment: @Mehur could you please put your function, I mean the JS portion of your code into jsfiddle or somewhere alike where we can see "everything" more clearly?

Comment: Glad to know! :) 
Could you share what was the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

try this..
Post data using `FormData()` formdata post file also.
To get all your form inputs, including the `type="file"` you need to use ***FormData object***.

```
$('#post').on('click', function (e) {
    var file_data = $("#userfile").prop("files")[0];      
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append("userfile", file_data)
    $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href+'/post',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
   return false;
});
```

For more...https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Ok but i have more inputs in that form which i don't want to send through ajax. Any way to send only file data?

Comment: Not working . Getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined(…)`

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
public function upload()
{
$this->load->library('upload');

if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']))
{
    if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] != 4)
    {
         // Image file configurations
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('myfile');
    }
  }
 }
```

View

```
<form id="myform" action="<?php base_url('controller/method'); ?>" method="post">
<input type="file" name="myfile">
```

```
("#myform").submit(function(evt){
evt.preventDefault();

var url = $(this).attr('action');
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}); // End: $.ajax()           

}); // End: submit()
```

Let me know if any query

Comment: A good tutorial here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270179/how-can-i-upload-image-with-ajax-in-codeigniter

Comment: Working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to submit the form not on click but on submit ... give the form an id and then on submit put ajax

HTML

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'post'); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart(site_url("upload/post",$attributes), ?>
    <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile" value="">
    <button id="post">Submit</button>
  <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

$('#post').on('submit', function () {

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("userfile",$("#userfile")[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href+'/post',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData
        });
```

CONTROLLERS

```
public function post() 
    {
        $this->load->library("upload");
        $file = $this->common->nohtml($this->input->post("userfile"));
    $this->upload->initialize(array( 
           "upload_path" => 'upload',
           "overwrite" => FALSE,
           "max_filename" => 300,
           "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
        ));

    $data = $this->upload->data();

    $image_file = $data['file_name'];

    $this->data_models->update($this->data->INFO, array(
      "image" => $image_file
        )
      );
```

}

Comment: Not working. Getting `upload:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)1